# Not Getting Lowest Value with min() Function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working with the min() function in Google Sheets. When I enter the range {-5,0,5} as an argument I'm getting back 0 as result when I would expect -5. Am I missing something? Why am I not getting -5?

Answer (score 0):

here you go! :) I made this example to make it easy for you to follow, just see the screenshot below

[image: screenshot!]

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
=min({-5,0,5})
```

If A1 is `={-5,0,5}`, then `=min(A1)` will work too.

But if A1 is `{-5,0,5}` (or any other set of values), then `=min(A1)` will be 0.

---

This is because `{-5,0,5}` is a "label" and not a "value". See [=CELL("type", A1)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267071?hl=en-GB).